# MVC | Telerik | Kendo UI | How to set the .Value via Javascript

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-multiselect

Can anyone help me out to dynamically set the Value Property of the Kendo UI Multiselect.
I need to show multiple values in this
If i have a single item like .Value("1") will show the selected item in the Control but what if i want to pass multiple values like .Value(["1","2"])

I have the List of Ids separated by comma but when i pass this value to the .Value property it doesn't show any selected item.

How i can achieve this using JavaScript.

The below code doesn't work

```
var vardata = "1,2";
$("#TestPoints").data("kendoMultiSelect").value(vardata);
```

Comment: The following action did the trick, i dont know if this is actually what we have to do it
but the below code worked

I created a list of all the Values as s string like, in javascript

var vardata = '[' + Comma Seperate Values likem 1,2 + ']';

    e.g. vardata = '[1,2]'

Later, i parsed the data to JSON and supplied to the .Value() property of kendoui Multiselect

    $("#TestPoints").data("kendoMultiSelect").value(JSON.parse(testpointids));

This is done on .cshtml page using javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following action did the trick, i dont know if this is actually what we have to do it but the below code worked I created a list of all the Values as s string like, in javascript

```
var vardata = '[' + Comma Seperate Values likem 1,2 + ']'; 
e.g. vardata = '[1,2]'
```

Later, i parsed the data to JSON and supplied to the .Value() property of kendoui Multiselect

```
$("#TestPoints").data("kendoMultiSelect").value(JSON.parse(testpointids));
```

This is done on .cshtml page using javascript.